# Include tag in Django template language -- what can I pass in to it?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

OK, so again there is likely a "simple" solution to this, but I am a beginner and nothing seems simple to me.

I have a view and a template that shows the attributes of an instance of a Car class that I have modeled. This Car class has a ManyToMany relationship with my custom User class. The template that show the attributes of a given instance of Car has many variables. The view for each Car works fine. Here is what I can't get to work:

I have a user profile page for each instance of User. From that page, I want to show the attributes of each Car that a particular User has "favorited." I am unable to figure out how to do this.

I have tried the {% include %} tag to include a snippet of the Car template and then use a for statement to iterate through the favorite set of the User. In theory, this would populate the User page with each Car that they have "favorited" and show its attributes. However, I do not know how to pass the {% include %} tag the proper context so the attributes are populated correctly for each instance of Car. Is this possible?

Is there a simpler way to do it that I am just overlooking?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`{% include ... with ... %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#include) syntax:

```
{% for car in user.favorite_cars.all %}
    {% include "car.html" with name=car.name year=car.year %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another alternative is the [`{% with %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#with) tag:

```
{% for car in user.favorite_cars.all %}
    {% with name=car.name year=car.year %}
        {% with color=car.color %}
            {% include "car.html" %}
        {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

**UPDATE**: If data for the template can't be obtained from the `Car` model then you have to use the [custom inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('car.html')
def show_car(car):
    history = get_history_for_car(car)
    return {'name': car.name, 'history': history}
```

And the in the template:

```
{% load my_car_tags %}

{% for car in user.favorite_cars.all %}
    {% show_car car %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer. The problem with that solution is that the attributes for each car are not a part of the car model. They are derived from an API call. I guess I could add them as fields in the model? They change frequently, however, and they need to be generated dynamically. I guess the database could store the generic API call, then I could "with" the fields in an include statement? There are about 12 of them, though. That seems unwieldy.

Comment: Yes, you can add them as the model fields.  Or use the custom inclusion tag. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to include a function in my model "get_data()" that would make the API calls and update the variables. I really appreciate your help. I'd upvote you, but I have no reputation :(